# how to declare the sysconf return value in global array declaration?

Tags: c, global-variables

I wrote a program for maintaining all open file descriptor details .

So, I used sysconf function to get the runtime max open file descriptor to be allowed .

if array declaration is not in the global means it doesn't say any error .its work fine.

This is my program,

```
#define MAX_CLIENT sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX)   
int arr[MAX_CLIENT];
main ()

{
 printf("%ld \n",MAX_CLIENT);
}
```

when i do the compilation it saying error

```
error: variably modified ‘arr’ at file scope
```

Then I checked with cc -E option.After the preprocessor works, the programs looks like this

```
int arr[sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX)];
main ()

{
 printf("%ld \n",sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX));
}
```

this is my problem how to declare the array in global .

Answer (score 3):

The easiest option is to dynamically allocate the array using `malloc()`:

```
int *arr;

int main(void) {
  arr = malloc(sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX) * sizeof(int));
  ...
  free(arr);
}
```

The code that you have right now *would* work, but only if `arr` were declared inside a function. It would then make use of the C99 feature called [variable-length arrays](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a global array in size that isn't known at compilation time.

The simplest solution is to define a global pointer, and assign it to a memory allocated in the begin of `main`.